# PowerShell copy an array completely

Tags: arrays, powershell

I'm trying to create a complete copy of an existing array. Every time I try this it doesn't seem to work. The thing is that I'm modifying the Object names inside the new copied array, but they're also changed in the original array..

The code below is highly simplified as there is a lot more happening then only renaming object names but it proves the point I think.

**Some example code:**

```
Function Get-Fruits {
    Param (
        $Fruits = @('Banana', 'Apple', 'Pear')
    )
    foreach ($F in $Fruits) {
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            Type = $F
        }
    }
}

$FruitsOriginal = Get-Fruits

Function Rename-ObjectName {
    # Copy the array here
    $FruitsNew = $FruitsOriginal # Not a true copy
    $FruitsNew = $FruitsOriginal | % {$_} # Not a true copy
    $FruitsNew = $FruitsOriginal.Clone() # Not a true copy

    $FruitsNew | Get-Member | ? MemberType -EQ NoteProperty | % {

        $Name = $_.Name

        $FruitsNew | % {
            $_ | Add-Member 'Tasty fruits' -NotePropertyValue $_.$Name
            $_.PSObject.Properties.Remove($Name)
        }
    }
}

Rename-ObjectName
```

The desired result is 2 completely separate arrays.

**$FruitsOriginal**

```
Type
----
Banana
Apple
Pear
```

**$FruitsNew**

```
Tasty fruits
------------
Banana
Apple
Pear
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Hey DarkLite... when was the last time you had a tasty fresh _peer_?

Comment: 'The string's the thing' from the Scripting Guys and fruits in my case make it easier to demonstrate code, lol. But I'm more of a Banana fan if I have to be honest. Hope you get elected, I voted for you :)

Comment: You might have me confused with someone else as I am not in the running (or am I?). Also I was trying to point out that peer was spelled wrong

Comment: Always so serious ;) Fixed it, thx! You are correct, [voted](http://stackoverflow.com/election?cb=1) for the wrong [Matt](http://stackoverflow.com/users/444991/matt). In any case, I always appreciate your help, so a special thank you 2 u.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Powershell - Copying an array of reference types as value types instead](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12481758/powershell-copying-an-array-of-reference-types-as-value-types-instead)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use serialisation to deep clone your array:

```
#Original data
$FruitsOriginal = Get-Fruits

# Serialize and Deserialize data using BinaryFormatter
$ms = New-Object System.IO.MemoryStream
$bf = New-Object System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter
$bf.Serialize($ms, $FruitsOriginal)
$ms.Position = 0

#Deep copied data
$FruitsNew = $bf.Deserialize($ms)
$ms.Close()
```

Comment: Fully awesome! Thank you very much Jaco :)

Comment: Is there an object "depth" limit to this approach? Also, worth noting that the above only works if $FruitsOriginal.GetType().IsSerializable -eq $true

Comment: Sorry, one more thing: if $FruitsOriginal contains nested objects, then each nested object's .GetType().IsSerializable would also have to be $true for this to work.

Answer (score 22):

```
# Copy the array here
$FruitsCopy = @()
$FruitsCopy = $FruitsCopy + $FruitsOriginal
```

Comment: `$FruitsCopy = @() + $FruitsOriginal` works too

Answer (score 9):

Since Powershell 3.0, same approach as [Jaco's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29699129/444172) but using  [PSSerializer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.psserializer(v=vs.85).aspx).
It uses a `CliXML` format compatible with `Export-Clixml` & `Import-Clixml` and personally I find it easier to read.
In theory, supports a nested hierarchy up to `[int32]::MaxValue` levels-deep

```
#   Original data
$FruitsOriginal     =    Get-Fruits
#   Serialize and Deserialize data using PSSerializer:
$_TempCliXMLString  =   [System.Management.Automation.PSSerializer]::Serialize($FruitsOriginal, [int32]::MaxValue)
$FruitsNew          =   [System.Management.Automation.PSSerializer]::Deserialize($_TempCliXMLString)
#   Deep copy done.
```

Comment: That's a great tip! Thanks for adding 

Comment: You're welcome. More than once I was fighting with $_.psobject.Copy() before stumbling on this solution :)

Answer (score 2):

If you're copying an array of objects/value that contains all "truthy" values, or you want to quickly filter out null and "falsey" values, then this works great:

```
$FruitsNew = $FruitsOriginal|?{$_}
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you need to do with the objects, and if they're simple enough (as in your example), you could just replace them with a new object.

`$NewFruits = $FruitsOriginal | %{ [PSCustomObject]@{ "Tasty Fruits" = $_.Type } }`