# Powershell ScriptBlock closure: am I missing something?

Tags: powershell, arraylist, closures, scopes, scriptblock

I have been struggling with this for several hours now and after reading many threads about ScriptBlocks, Closures, scopes etc I still don't see what's wrong in my code.

Let me explain: I have a main script that dynamically generates an HTML page using [PSWriteHTML](https://github.com/EvotecIT/PSWriteHTML) module and ScriptBlocks.

As I have a lot of PSWriteHTML pages to write, I use an arrayList of ScriptBlocks to generate the code with different set of values each time (corresponding to different servers), these ScriptBlocks being executed into a **foreach** loop.

This is done using the **Save-utilizationReport** function (I have only kept the relevant code):

```
function Save-utilizationReport ($currentDate, $navLinksScriptBlock, $htmlScriptBlockArray, $emeaTotalNumberOfCalls, $namTotalNumberOfCalls, $apacTotalNumberOfCalls, $path, $logFilePath) {
    
    [...]

    # Using Script Blocks, add the pages generated during the analysis to the HTML Report
    foreach($htmlScriptBlock in $htmlScriptBlockArray){
        Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock ($htmlScriptBlock)
    }

    [...]
}
```

The ScriptBlock are created using set of values gathered from a list of servers' logs and added to the arrayList of ScriptBlocks in the **Create-utilizationReportPage** function (again, I've only kept the relevant code):

```
function Create-utilizationReportPage ($matchedLines, $ipAddress, $hostname, $pageId, $utilisationReportTemplate, $htmlScriptBlockArray) {

# Retrieve the content of the Utilisation Report Template as a RAW string (Here-String)
$htmlPageCodeBlock = Get-Content $utilisationReportTemplate -Raw

# Create the Script Block that contains the HTML page
$htmlPageScriptBlock = {
    
    # Get the "Total number of calls" information
    $timeArray = $matchedLines.time
    $participantNumberArray = $matchedLines.participantNumber

    [...]
    
    # Update the page ID in the template
    $htmlPageCodeBlock = $htmlPageCodeBlock -replace '%PAGE_ID%', "$pageId"
    
    # Update the page header information in the template
    $htmlPageCodeBlock = $htmlPageCodeBlock -replace '%PAGE_HEADER%', "$ipAddress [$hostname]"
    
    Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock ([scriptblock]::Create($htmlPageCodeBlock))
}.GetNewClosure()

# Add the Page's script block to the Script Blocks array
$htmlScriptBlockArray.Add($htmlPageScriptBlock)
}
```

These are called in the script below:

```
$currentDate = Get-CorrectDate $latestFolder

# The global Log file
$logFilePath = "$scriptPath/Logs/logs_$currentDate.txt"

$serversList = "$scriptPath/Config/$configFileName"

# If the Servers list exists, retrieve the Servers list
if (Test-Path $serversList) {
    # Get the data from the file
    [xml]$servers = Get-Content $serversList

    # Select only the Servers information
    $nodes = $servers.SelectNodes("//server")
        
    try {
    
        [...]
    
        # Iterate through the Servers list
        foreach ($node in $nodes) {
        
            # Get the Server IP Address
            $ipAddress = $node.ip
            
            # Get the Server Hostname
            $hostname = $node.hostname
            
            # Get the "Debug Utilization" lines from the logbundle's syslog files
            $matchedLines = [System.Collections.ArrayList]@(Find-UtilizationLinesInLogs $currentDate "$scriptPath\Data\$currentDate\logs_$ipAddress" "host:server:  \[USAGE\] : \{`"1`" : ")[-1]

            # Add the Server's participants throughout the day
            switch ($hostname) {
                {$_.Contains("emea")} {
                    # Update EMEA total number of participants
                    Update-ZoneTotalParticipants ([ref]$emeaServer) ([ref]$emeaTotalNumberOfCalls) $matchedLines
                }
                {$_.Contains("nam")} {
                    # Update NAM total number of participants
                    Update-ZoneTotalParticipants ([ref]$namServer) ([ref]$namTotalNumberOfCalls) $matchedLines
                }
                {$_.Contains("apac")} {
                    # Update APAC total number of participants
                    Update-ZoneTotalParticipants ([ref]$apacServer) ([ref]$apacTotalNumberOfCalls) $matchedLines
                }
            }
            
            # Get the CPU Utilization values lines from the logbundle's sysdebug files
            $cpu = Get-CpuUsage "$scriptPath\Data\$currentDate\logs_$ipAddress\sysdebug"

            # Get the Memory Utilization values lines from the logs' sysdebug files
            $memory = Get-MemoryUsage "$scriptPath\Data\$currentDate\logs_$ipAddress\sysdebug"

            # Export the "Debug Utilization" to a CSV file
            Save-csvUtilizationReport $matchedLines "$scriptPath\Output\$currentDate" "$ipAddress" "$hostname" $logFilePath

            # Draw graphs from the "Debug Utilization" information and then export it to an HTML File
            Create-utilizationReportPage $matchedLines "$ipAddress" "$hostname" $pageId $utilisationReportTemplate $htmlScriptBlockArray
            
            # Add the new navigation link to the Navigation Links array
            Add-htmlNavLink $navLinksArray "$ipAddress" "$hostname" $pageId $logFilePath
            
            # Increment the Page ID counter
            $pageId += 1
        }
    
        # Create an Here-String from the Navigation Links array
        $OFS = ""
        $navLinksCode =@"
        $($navLinksArray)
"@
        $OFS = " "

        # Create a script block from the Navigation Links
        $navLinksScriptBlock = [scriptblock]::Create($navLinksCode)

        # Save the daily HTML utilization report
        Save-utilizationReport $currentDate $navLinksScriptBlock $htmlScriptBlockArray $emeaTotalNumberOfCalls $namTotalNumberOfCalls $apacTotalNumberOfCalls "$scriptPath\Output\$currentDate" $logFilePath
    }
    catch
    {
        Write-Logs $logFilePath "Error: $($_.Exception.Message)"
        
        exit 1
    }
}
```

Everything is working fine and as expcted except for the first set of values in the first page which is somehow the sum of all the other set of values...

For example when I have 3 pages, I can see that the collected values are correct when the **Find-UtilizationLinesInLogs** function is executed:

1. **matchedLines.participantNumber**:
   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 5 5 5 5 4 4 4 4 4 12 14 14 15 16 16 16 7 7 7 7 8 14 17 18 19 18 19 19 20 16 16 16 15 7 7 7 7 5 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 1 1 0 0 0 3 6 5 5 5 5 9 14 16 18
2. **matchedLines.participantNumber**:
   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 8 9 10 10 10 10 9 9 9 9 9 9 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 9 4 12 15 11 14 14 13 12 12 12 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0
3. **matchedLines.participantNumber**:
   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 2 0 0 0 3 9 10 10 9 8 10 9 9 10 10 10 10 10 11 11 11 11 8 7 8 8 7 7 7 7 7 7 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 4 16 17 16 16

But when the ScriptBlocks are executed using the **Invoke-Command** in the **foreach** loop, the first batch of values is systematically the sum of the 3 sets of values while the following ones are correct:

1. **matchedLines.participantNumber inside Create-utilizationReportPage**:
   ***0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 5 6 6 7 7 5 5 5 8 29 33 34 34 34 36 34 25 26 26 26 27 32 36 37 38 37 35 34 36 32 31 32 26 26 29 25 22 20 18 17 17 17 6 6 6 6 3 3 2 2 2 5 8 7 7 7 10 25 31 32 34***
2. **matchedLines.participantNumber inside Create-utilizationReportPage**:
   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 8 9 10 10 10 10 9 9 9 9 9 9 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 9 4 12 15 11 14 14 13 12 12 12 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0
3. **matchedLines.participantNumber inside Create-utilizationReportPage**:
   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 2 0 0 0 3 9 10 10 9 8 10 9 9 10 10 10 10 10 11 11 11 11 8 7 8 8 7 7 7 7 7 7 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 4 16 17 16 16

I have tried many things without success so if someone has any hint of what can go wrong, it would be great!

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Any particular reason you're using `Invoke-Command` (instead of just `& $htmlPageCodeBlock`)?

Comment: It's going to be hard to reproduce your issue locally with all the external dependencies your scripts have. Can you remove any more code and *still* reproduce the issue? If not, the problem's in the code you just removed so try to isolate that part by removing something else. Rinse and repeat until you've got something that can be cut & pasted into a PowerShell console to reproduce...  (See the "minmal" heading in https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: With everything you've removed, it's unclear when and how you modify the objects stored in the lists you assign to `$matchedLines` <- this is likely where the problem is (or at least it'll tell us where)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen: actually no, I thought this was the best way to go. Does it change something? In the script, the `$matchedLines` values are never modified, I only parse the array and store the values in "per zone" arrays: `$emeaTotalNumberOfCalls`, `$namTotalNumberOfCalls` or `$apacotalNumberOfCalls`.

Comment: @mclayton: that's what I'll try today.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So! I finally found out what was wrong.

I suspected that my problem was related to **arrayList** copies or at least variable copies... so I tried to remove this part of the script where I extract the **$macthedLines** values and copy them into global arrays using references:

```
            # Add the Server's participants throughout the day
            switch ($hostname) {
                {$_.Contains("emea")} {
                    # Update EMEA total number of participants
                    Update-ZoneTotalParticipants ([ref]$emeaServer) ([ref]$emeaTotalNumberOfCalls) $matchedLines
                }
                {$_.Contains("nam")} {
                    # Update NAM total number of participants
                    Update-ZoneTotalParticipants ([ref]$namServer) ([ref]$namTotalNumberOfCalls) $matchedLines
                }
                {$_.Contains("apac")} {
                    # Update APAC total number of participants
                    Update-ZoneTotalParticipants ([ref]$apacServer) ([ref]$apacTotalNumberOfCalls) $matchedLines
                }
            }
```

And bingo, this time the values written down in the first PSWriteHTML page are the correct one!

So I focused on the **Update-ZoneTotalParticipants** function which is doing the values copy:

```
function Update-ZoneTotalParticipants ([ref][int]$ServerNumber, [ref][System.Collections.ArrayList]$totalNumberOfCalls, $values) {
    # If this is the first server to be analysed in the zone
    if ($ServerNumber.value -eq 1) {

        # Copy the Utilization lines of the server
        $totalNumberOfCalls.value = $values
        
        # Increment the zone's server counter
        $ServerNumber.value += 1
    }
    # If this at least the 2nd server to be analysed in the zone
    elseif ($ServerNumber.value -gt 1) {

        # Parse the server matched lines, get the participantNumber value and add it to the total
        0..($totalNumberOfCalls.value.Count - 1) | ForEach-Object {
            if ($_ -le ($values.Count - 1)) {
                $totalNumberOfCalls.value[$_].participantNumber = [int]($totalNumberOfCalls.value[$_].participantNumber) + [int]($values[$_].participantNumber)
            }
            # If there are less objects in the current server matched lines, add a 0 instead
            else {
                $totalNumberOfCalls.value[$_].participantNumber = [int]($totalNumberOfCalls.value[$_].participantNumber) + 0
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The only part of the code where **$matchedLines** is involved is `$totalNumberOfCalls.value = $values` so it certainly is were the array manipulation goes wrong.

So I dug around **ArrayList** copies or clones and found out that I was not doing a deep copy of the object and that it could cause issues.

I used ***Petru Zaharia***'s solution [in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45224302/4261655) to update the function:

```
        # Copy the Utilization lines of the server
        $totalNumberOfCalls.value = $values

# replaced with:

        # Copy the Utilization lines of the server : Serialize and Deserialize data using PSSerializer:
        $_TempCliXMLString = [System.Management.Automation.PSSerializer]::Serialize($matchedLines, [int32]::MaxValue)
        $totalNumberOfCalls.value = [System.Management.Automation.PSSerializer]::Deserialize($_TempCliXMLString)
```

And now everything works as expected.

Thanks guys for your support!